# EXT Plugin not able to merge web.xml in liferay 6.0.6 and Weblogic 10.3

Tags: weblogic, liferay, liferay-6, weblogic-10.x

I deployed liferay war on weblogic 10.3 and cretaed EXT which have changes in web.xml.
If i deploy this EXT,weblogic doesn't take these changes which is made by web.xml of EXT.

I googled it and found this is issue in liferay 6.0 and resolved in liferay 6.2
please go through below link for more info:
http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-13222

Howerver I found some workaround in liferay wiki which is suggesting to follow below steps.

1. copy somewhere existing web.xml
2. deploy EXT plugin
3. make plan.xml based on differences between the new web.xml and old one
4. use plan.xml in administration console

But still wondering how to create plan.xml in step3.

So would like to know how can i create plan.xml based on differnce between new web.xml and old one.

Comment: Can you give the wiki link? Also as a workaround I think you can even directly update the `web.xml` on the server.

Comment: Thanks for reply...here is the link http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Weblogic+tips#section-Weblogic+tips-EXT+plugins+and+web.xml+changes

Comment: the wiki contains a link to [`plan generator`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/wlplangenerator.html), that might help.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do a diff. Under Linux, open a console.
Try for example

```
diff web_old.xml web_new.xml > mydiff.patch
```

It will display the differences between the two files in a file called "mydiff.patch".

Now, you can patch the deployed web.xml (shutdown your server before) :

```
cd /path-of-the-web.xml-folder-on-the-server
patch -p0 < mydiff.patch
```

You can also use the `svn diff` command to make your diff file.
After these operations, restart your server.

Hope it helps.